# Get-SPWeb : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

In a system, when I run

```
Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb
```

It shows the error:

```
Get-SPWeb : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

But if I run

```
$sites = get-spsite ;
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    Write-Host 'Processing ' $site;
    get-spweb $site.Url
}
```

Everything works fine.

Anyone knows what can cause this issue?

UAC is Off, obviously, the account has permission to run the cmdlet, what else it can be? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you are running this against the same site collection url? get-spsite http://sitecollection naem | get-spweb

Comment: yes, same site collection

Comment: how many site collections you have? did you try with supplying the url as i mentioned

Comment: can not try it, since do not know the collection name. this code will run in different environment, and site collection are different. I'm just wondering why '|' not working.

Comment: Get-spsite will try to get all site collections and may be you have no access on it.

Comment: no, the account has access to all. otherwise, the foreach script won't work. But it does.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb
```

You will get a collection of all SPSites in the farm, and then you try to pass this array as an argument to get all SPWebs. The pipe `|` is only valid if you pass a single object (one SPSite) to the next operation. And that is exactly what you're doing in your second example. To get the first statement to work, you have to pass only one SPSite to get its SPWebs.

You need to type:

```
Get-SPSite -Identity https://MySiteCollectionURL | Get-SPWeb
```

In your second attempt you're only getting the root SPWeb which has the same URL as the Site Collection. You're not getting all SPWebs in that SPSite.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below link
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263291.aspx

which says.....................
Farm Administrators group Members of the Farm Administrators group have Full Control permissions to and responsibility for all servers in the server farm. Members can perform all administrative tasks in Central Administration for the server or server farm. They can assign administrators to manage service applications, which are instances of shared services. This group does not have access to individual sites or their content.
................................

So, you have to grant user policy for each web app (full read).
regards,
Nicholas A. Souza

Comment: the account has been granted full read permission, same issue. even with full control permission, same issue. weird.